# Bootstrap carousel cycle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have standard bootstrap 4.5 carousel with this code:

```
 <script>
     $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
 </script>

<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="500">
                            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/fullsize/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="500">
                         <img src="assets/img/portfolio/fullsize/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        </div>
                       
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

I need the slides to scroll automatically. When I hover over the carousel of the mouse, the cycle is interrupted. I want the carousel to continue sliding. Please take me the advice ... thank you for all4

Answer (score 0):

Pass `false` to `pause` option when you initialize the carousel. Alternatively, you can use data attributes as well. Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/#options

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: false
})
```

```css
#carouselExampleSlidesOnly{
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="500">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x151" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="500">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x152" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```